# Solving for x and y in qcauchy() given its quantiles in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, distribution, nlm

**Background:**

`qcauchy(p, location, scale)` is an built-in base R function. In this function, "**location**" indicates the **center** and "**scale**" indicates the **speadoutness** of a **symmetric** bell-like curve (just like a normal distribution). **"location"** can be any number (negative, positive, non-integer etc.). And **"scale"** can be any number larger than **"0"**. Also, **"p"** is probability thus 0 <= p <= 1.

**Coding Question:**

Only as 1 example, suppose I know `qcauchy(p = c(.025, .975), location = x, scale = y ) = c(-12.7062, 12.7062 )`, THEN, is there a way I can **find** out what **x** and **y** could reasonably be (i.e., within some margin of error)?

**P.S.:** As a small possible start, can `nlm()` (i.e., non-linear minimazation) help here? Or the fact the most right-hand side [i.e., `c(-12.7062, 12.7062 )` ], are the same number with opposite signs.

Comment: This question should probably be on 
[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), not here. 

I do not think that the scale parameter is allowed to be negative 
as stated in your question. 

Since the Cauchy distribution is symmetric, if you have two values 
like in your example where `qcauchy(c(p, 1-p), x, y) = c(-a, a)`
then x = 0.   More generally, if 
`qcauchy(c(p, 1-p), x, y) = c(a, b)` then x = (a + b) / 2

Comment: And further to G5W if `a` in his equation is chosen so that `y = 1` then the solution to `qcauchy(p, 1-p), x, y)  = s * c(-a, a)` is `x = 0, y = s`.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a package for solving a system of nonlinear equations `nleqslv`.
I tried the following

```
library(nleqslv)

f <- function(x) {
    y <- c(-12.7062, 12.7062) - qcauchy(c(.025,.975), location=x[1],  scale=x[2]) 
    y
}

nleqslv(c(1,1), f)
```

and got this answer

```
$x
[1] 5.773160e-15 9.999996e-01

$fvec
[1]  1.421085e-14 -1.421085e-14

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 1

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 1
```

Comment: You could also use `optim` like this: `optim(c(1,1), function(x) sum(f(x)^2))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, could you please explain a bit more how you `optim` works, because my goal is to make a function out of this so it works for any input?

Comment: The sum of squares function shown has a minimum value of zero at which point the equation is satisfied.  The solution in the answer is shorter but this variation could be useful if it were desired to only use base R.  At any rate it makes use of Bhas' `f` so just added this as a comment.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, got it thank you so much! I wish there was a way I could accept or upvote your answer. BTW, could I also use `nlm()` here? How could that look like?

Comment: With nlm or any minimization function you would ue the sum of squares function in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bhas answer, you can first use your intuition and recognise that location must be zero, since the distribution is symmetric and - as you pointed out - the two values are the same up to their sign. So in this case the distribution is symmetric around zero.

To find the scale, use Bhas answer or

```
find_scale_template <- function(q)
  function(y) {
    (qcauchy(p = .975, location = 0, scale = y) - q)^2
  }
}
find_scale <- find_scale_template(12.7062)
optimize(find_scale, interval = c(0, 10))
```